# getting 404 error for my service while exposing through istio ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I deployed **istio** in my **aks** cluster using [enter link description here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/), exposed istio sample applications(product_page,)through **istio gatewayservice,** it worked fine as expected, but when I exposed my service, showing **404** error.

Here is my gateway.yaml

[image]

Here is my virtual-service.yaml

[image]

Comment: Hi harish hari, have you tried to use `istioctl analyze `? Istio documentation [link](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl-analyze/). It allows to detect common problems such as lack of sidecar injection in the namespace.

Comment: you only exposed the mentioned routes inside the virtualservice and I think you trying to to access / (root URL) which is not exposed.

Comment: I updated uri: value as regex: /*, it worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments setting regex value to `regex: /*` solved the issue in this case.

It is possible to see and inspect what is exposed and what is accessible in the istio ingress by generating the mesh graph using kiali as mentioned on [this documentation page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/).

This is especially useful when working with regex uri match method as it is very easy to mess up the scope of a regex value.